# Close WPF window that host Pages

Tags: c#, wpf, windows, xaml

Im currently learning C# WPF. Now Im just trying to understand how navigation works.

I have created a test app that includes 2 buttons. One that navigates to the next page and another to open a new window.

Navigation between pages is not a problem.

I was able to navigate from page1 to page2 using a button. The code below is written in my Page1.xaml.cs

```
private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Page2 p2 = new Page2();
    this.NavigationService.Navigate(p2);
}
```

The problem is when I try to open a new window and close the previous one with a button, it doesnt work. (I also wrote this on my Page1.xaml.cs)

```
private void button_Copy_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window1 win1 = new Window1();
    win1.Show();
    this.Close();
}
```

Its giving me an error code CS1061 and telling me that it does not contain a definition for 'close'.

Here is the complete code of my Page1.xaml.cs:

```
namespace WpfApplication1
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Interaction logic for Page1.xaml
    /// </summary>
    public partial class Page1 : Page
    {
        public Page1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Page2 p2 = new Page2();
            this.NavigationService.Navigate(p2);
        }

        private void button_Copy_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window1 win1 = new Window1();
            win1.Show();
            this.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: there is no method `Close` in [`Page`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.page(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Default if there is no method, what should I do?

Comment: @syn3rgy that's up to you I guess. [But you still cannot call a method or access a class member that does not exist.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383961.aspx)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a bit of a guess, as I haven't seen enough of your code. If the call *this.Close()* is placed **outside** the class defining the window that you're trying to close, there's no such method in the scope of *this*.

Comment: I just edited my post to include the whole code .. Im a total beginner at this so can you explain it in thoroughly.

Comment: @syn3rgy is it correct to assume that you are not familiar with object oriented programming? How about C# classes?

Comment: @Default Yes .. I wanted to try a C# and didnt know where to begin.

Comment: @syn3rgy Then I would suggest reading the [MSDN C# tutorials](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288436(v=vs.71).aspx) which IMO are very good at learning C#. At least understand the basic concepts before jumping on the complexities of WPF

Comment: @syn3rgy I see the code now. One thing that I notice is that there seems to be some unclearity regarding the difference between *window* and *page*. Did you intend in your method *button_Copy_Click* to close the current window and open up a new one? If so, I believe you're a bit off the correct approach.

Comment: @KonradViltersten Yes, I wanted to close the current window and open a new one. Whats the correct approach then?

Comment: @syn3rgy It's a bit more complex than you might think and the exact choice of approach would depend on your exact aim. **A suggestion out of many possible** would be to open a **modal window**, which is as simple as using *OpenDialog()* instead of *Open()* on your window. That will block the execution of the code until the window is opened. Then, if you have the calls in a *while(true)* loop, a new window will open automatically. Bottom line, you might want to consider a global runner that opens/closes the windows, rather than have a window open another.

Comment: @KonradViltersten That seems a good answer, however Im a total beginner at this language. Can you help me step by step? Or if not, at least can you point me to the right direction where I can learn how to the this?

Comment: @syn3rgy Yes, I can. As I see it, **this** question has been answered. Please accept it as such. Now, I hear that even though this question is taken care of, it still feel unclear to you regarding the whole concept. My recommendation is that you start over with a new project and digest the whole shabang into smaller parts, so that you can ask individual questions for each (you might also discover that some of those more specific questions already have an answer here on StackOverflow). As a first step, I'd recommend to create a new XAML desktop applications (no pages, just windows).

Comment: @KonradViltersten OK, thanks for the information. I will follow what I have learned here.

Answer (score 1):

Use

```
this.parent
```

To access the Window the page is in

```
var goToWindow = new Window1();
goToWindow.Show();
Window windowToClose = (Window)(this.Parent);
windowToClose.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured out a work around. What you could do, is create a button at the bottom of the window that hosts the page and from that button, set the open new window and close property on click. (If you want to close the page and open a new window).

This is what I mean

```
<Grid>
    <!--Your page frame -->
    <Frame Name="buildcaseFrame" NavigationUIVisibility="Hidden" />

    <!--This button will appear on all the pages-->
    <!--You can choose where to place the button-->
    <StackPanel VerticalAlignment="Bottom">
        <Button x:Name="btnCloseButton" ToolTip="Go Back to Main Menu Without Saving" Cursor="Hand" Content="Cancel" Click="closeButton_Click"/>
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

This will allow you to close the page and open a new window. Like so...

```
private void BtnCloseButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    Window1 win1 = new Window1();
    win1.Show();
    this.Close();
}
```